# Scheme , seaching a list regarding a password entered

Tags: scheme

I am new in scheme programming. What I am supposed to do is creating a password system which will consist of the characters in the database named pool. What I want to do is to check if the user's entered a password that consists of these valid characters or they entered an invalid character. What Ive tried is:

```
(define pool (list 'A 'B 'C 'D 'E 'F 'G 'H 'I 'J  'K 'L  'M 'N  'O 'P 'Q 'R 'S  'T 'U 'V 'W 'X  'Y 'Z 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f 'g 'i 'j 'k 'l 'm 'n 'o 'p 'r 'q 's 't 'u 'v 'w 'x 'y 'z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0  '?  '!  `!    '% '^ '& '* '_ '- '+ '= "{" "[" "}" "]" ":" ";" "@" "'" "~" "#" "|"  '< "," ">" "." ))

(define us-pass(list 'ali   'ahmet  'ayşe))
(define (member? x list)
     (if (null? list) #f                             
         (if (equal? x (car list))  #t                  
              (member? x (cdr list))))) 


(define (is-in-list k a)
    (if (member '(string-ref k a) pool) true false )) 





(define (take-pass pass)
  (if (>=(string-length pass) 15) (let ([password pass] [ name (car us-pass)]) (list name pass)) "The password must be longer than 15 characters") 
  (let ([counter 0]) 
  (if (is-in-list pass counter) ((+ counter 1)(is-in-list pass counter)) "Invalid characters")))
```

But this does not seem helpful. If there is anyone who can help me I 'd be so happy.

Comment: You should explain what you expect to happen and what happens instead, "not helpful" is, uh, not helpful ;)

Comment: Found number of mistakes in a quick glance. 1) `'(string-ref k a)` is just a literal value so it doesn't refer a value in the given string. 2) `(member '(string-ref k a) pool)` (probably) tries to check if the value is in pool however `string-ref` returns character and `pool` contains symbol and string. So it'll never return true value. 3) `if` expression in `take-pass` seems wrongly used.